# How to rbind for (n-1) columns

Tags: r

I'm looking to do the simple following task;

Imagine a dataframe with 3 rows and 5 columns;

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  2  3  4  5
2  3  4  5  6  7
3  2  3  4  5  6
```

I want to add another constant row to only the last 4 columns

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  2  3  4  5
2  3  4  5  6  7
3  2  3  4  5  6
4     5  5  5  5
```

How may I be able to accomplish this? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your original dataframe is called `df` and you have data of length `ncol(df)-1` in a vector called `data.to.add`:

```
rbind(df, c(NA, data.to.add))
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer - however, I am afraid that I was not clear the last time I posted the question. I need to add a constant as the last row.
(this is important as the vector 'data.to.add' cannot be defined)

Comment: How are you defining this constant? Can you do `data.to.add <- rep(5, ncol(df) - 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

here is a function:

your input data:

```
df<-    
fread("  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  2  3  4  5
      2  3  4  5  6  7
      3  2  3  4  5  6")
```

Example data:

```
a=df;b=rep(5,4)
```

function:

```
    rbind.filling <- function(a,b) {
    n_col<-max(ncol(a),ncol(b))
    if(is.null(dim(a))) {a<-matrix(c(rep(NA,n_col-length(a)),a),nrow=1);;colnames(a)<-names(b)} else {
        b<-matrix(c(rep(NA,n_col-length(b)),b),nrow=1);colnames(b)<-names(a)}
    return(rbind(a,b))
}
```

call function:

```
rbind.filling(a,b)
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
# 1:  1  1  2  3  4  5
# 2:  2  3  4  5  6  7
# 3:  3  2  3  4  5  6
# 4: NA NA  5  5  5  5

rbind.filling(b,a)
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
# 1: NA NA  5  5  5  5
# 2:  1  1  2  3  4  5
# 3:  2  3  4  5  6  7
# 4:  3  2  3  4  5  6
```